# How to convert .docx to .pdf in Python 3 without win32com or comtypes?

Tags: python, pdf, heroku, docx

I'm building a Flask app hosted on Heroku which requires me to convert .docx files into .pdf files. When just hosting the Flask app on my computer, the win32com.client library works perfectly. However, when I try to include win32com.cient as a requirement for the Heroku 'requirements.txt', it crashes before building the Heroku app properly.

The error message always has to do with how win32com seems to be written in Python2, so in the code somewhere, the print statement doesn't include the parenthesis with the print method, whereas Python3 now requries these parenthesis.

I've looked many places, but I cannot seem to find a solution that works with the Heroku servers. I've also tried to use the unoconv library, but it does not seem to be working either.